# Linq - Join results from 2 columns from same table

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I would like to join results from a table, to sum up the results from a where condition on 2 different rows, as this code:

```
        var a = (from o in _DB.Services
                where (o.description.Contains(searchText) || o.nom.Contains(searchText))
                orderby o.date
                select new { results = ?????, id = ?????? }).Take(maxResults).ToList();
```

What can I put, in order to take into account the results=???? and id=???

Thanks

Comment: What columns are you wanting to retrieve?

Comment: Hi Mattyommo, several columns from the table, in my case 2 columns (description and nom), but in some cases 3 columns

Comment: If the description or the nom contains the search text would you like to select whichever one matches? Or both regardless? What about the id? Does that depend on the match too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, can't you just do the following?

```
var a = (from o in _DB.Services
            where (o.description.Contains(searchText) || o.nom.Contains(searchText))
            orderby o.date
            select new  
                   { 
                       results = o.description,
                       id = o.nom
                   })
            .Take(maxResults)
            .ToList();
```